Unable to list and upload dataset to SAP ObjectStore AWS S3 Bucket
Tutorial I am following :- Ingest Live Data into your House Price Predictor with SAP AI Core | SAP Tutorials
I am trying out a simple House price prediction Tutorial by SAP on BTP using the AI Core service. I want to upload the training data to AWS using the ObjectStore service, so I create an instance of it and generate service keys. The ObjectStore provisions an AWS S3 Bucket and provide access_key_id, bucket name and other important stuff in the Service key.
I Download the AWS CLI, then use
aws configure
then provide all the details provided by the service key. then
 aws s3 cp train.csv s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/example-dataset/house-price-toy/data/jan/train.csv
the command above gives SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED, so tried to download and store the certificate using openssl but it gave error as well, so ultimately resorted to --no-verify-ssl option (unsafe I know).
when trying to use 
aws s3 ls
It gives an error

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

when uploading with --no-ssl-verify option it gives

upload Failed: An error occurred (403) when calling the PutObject operation: Forbidden

Note: I am working behind a corporate Proxy.
I dont even have a clue on where to check the IAM permissions since the bucket is provisioned by SAP.
Tried the tutorials in the technology blogs of SAP Community, but to no avail.
